# Lock icon suddenly appearing on folders in Ubuntu's /dev/sda8 partition

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot, inode, lock

I'm encountering an issue on my Ubuntu system where folders in the **/dev/sda8** partition shows a lock icon for some time then it goes away. It happened twice. In that locked state if I try to run any node module (ex: PM2), I got an error that says "Exec Format Error". That locked state mysteriously goes away automatically after some time (maybe after some restarts)

**I'm using Ubuntu 22 using dual boot system with Windows 10.**

Is there a mounting issue, how can I fix this immediately when it happens?